# Proving an inequality regarding a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on question 13, section 4.1 of Krantz's book "Complex Variables: A Physical
Approach"

$p(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ with leading coefficient 1.  All zeros of $p(z)$ lie in the unit disc.  Prove that for $z$ large, $$|p(z)|\geq \frac{9|z|^k}{10}.$$

I've been stuck for awhile and tried to use the book hint, that this would follow immediately for $\lvert\frac{1}{z}\lvert<\frac{1}{\max_{0\leq \leq k-1} \{|a_j|+1} \frac{1}{10k}$.

Even with this I am having trouble progressing.  What I've done so far is simply to let $$p(z)=z^k+a_{k-1}z^{k-1}+\dots+a_1 z+a_0=z^k(1+a_{k-1}\frac{1}{z^{k-1}}+\dots+a_0\frac{1}{z^k})\geq z^k(1+a_{k-1}\frac1z+\dots+a_1\frac1z+a_0\frac1z)$$ for $z$ large.

Comment: $|p(z)|\geq |z|^k-|a_{k-1}z^{k-1}|-\cdots-|a_0|$. Now factor out $|z|^k$.

Comment: Then $|p(z)|\geq |z|^k(1-|a_{k-1}|\frac{1}{|z|}-\dots-|a_0|\frac{1}{|z^k|})$, so it remains to show that $1-|a_{k-1}|\frac{1}{|z|}-\dots-|a_0|\frac{1}{|z^k|}\geq \frac{9}{10}$ for $z$ large.

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$

Comment: Here's my thought process right now:  This is equivalent to showing $|a_{k-1}\frac{1}{|z|}+\dots+|a_0|\frac{1}{|z^k|}\leq\frac{1}{10}$.  Now, $|a_{k-1}\frac{1}{|z|}+\dots+|a_0|\frac{1}{|z|} \leq \frac{|a_{k-1}|}{\max\{|a_j|+1\}}\frac{1}{10k}+\dots+\frac{|a_{0}|}{\max\{|a_j|+1\}}\frac{1}{10k} \leq \frac{1}{10k}+\dots+\frac{1}{10k}=\frac{k}{10k}=\frac{1}{10}$

Comment: You can take $|z|\geq \max\{|a_j|\}k10^k$ to get it. (This looks similar to what you are doing, but you must explicitly state $|z|$).

Comment: Yes, I used $\lvert\frac{1}{z}\lvert<\frac{1}{\max_{0\leq \leq k-1} \{|a_j|+1\}}\frac{1}{10k}$.  Forgot to mention, my apologies.